# Can't Lync 2010 be installed in windows 2003 server?

Tags: windows, lync-2010, lync

I have asked our IT team to install Lync 2010 in my Windows 2003 server machine.

IT person told that it can't be installed in Windows 2003 server.

Is it not compatible with Windows 2003 server or any other extra software update do we need to install?

I am using Windows 2003 server standard edition sp2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lync 2010 requires Windows Server 2008 or later. The previous release, OCS 2007 R2, can be installed on Windows 2003.